# AWS Quicksight incremental load in SPICE Duplicate data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

When i am uploading incremental data into SPICE getting duplicate records , is there any configuration in Quicksight which help to avoid duplicate into Quicksight .

Any help greatly appreciated .

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Dealing with the same issue when we update or delete records old than the incremental refresh period.